# hypothesis testing with bootstrap confidence intervals

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap, hypothesis-test

I'm trying to do some hypothesis testing with a bootstrap confidence interval, but am having some trouble setting up the bootstrap. The goal is to test the null at theta=1 and at level 0.05. I've provided a sample of the data that is being used below:

```
y <- c(3,5,3,1,2,1,2,1,0,2,4,3,1,4,1,2,2,0,4,2,2,4,0,2,1)
```

Within the bootstrap, I'm also trying to work with a numerical optimization with the following: `dpois(data,lambda=exp(x)` . I've provided the code I've generated below:

```
nboot<-1000
bootxbar <- rep(NA,nboot)
for (i in 1:nboot) {
  data <- y[sample(1:n,replace=TRUE)]
  bootxbar[i]<-function(x) dpois(data,lambda=exp(x))
}
quantile(bootxbar,c(0.025,0.975))
```

The error is as follows:

> Error in bootxbar[i] <- function(x) dpois(y, lambda = exp(x)) : 
>     incompatible types (from closure to logical) in subassignment type fix

Comment: `bootxbar[i]<-function(x) dpois(data,lambda=exp(x))` tries to assign a function to a part of a vector.

Comment: @thelatemail Oh, then what would be the best way to correct that? I'm trying to have it run a poisson within the bootstrap.